# Typescript, no 'window' events when adding an import statement

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, window-load

So I'm pretty new to typescript, javascript and web-shizzles (I normally build native apps). But I'm experimenting with Phaser3 and use VSCode with typescript to transpile the javascript files. First I used namespaces (C# background), but apparently that's not the way to go in typescript, so I removed the namespaces and used export with corresponding import statements.

The problem: It took me a while to figure out that my window event (window.onload) doesn't fire because of importing a required type. This event is kind of the entry point to the app. Suggestions for other ways to kick start the project are always welcome. Here is the code:

window.onload DOES NOT FIRE:

```
import { Boot } from "./Boot";

window.onload = () => {
    console.log("Test");
    Boot.runApp();
}
```

After removing the 'import', window.onload FIRES!

```
//import { Boot } from "./Boot";

window.onload = () => {
    console.log("Test");
    //Boot.runApp();
}
```

Boot.ts

```
imports...

export class Boot {
        static runApp() {
            console.log("RUN APP!!");
//Start the game... (code removed)

        }
}
```

This is my tsconfig:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "module": "system",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "outDir": "bin/js/",
        "outFile": "bin/js/game.js"
    }, 

    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
        ],

    "files":[
        "./tsDefinitions/nineslice.d.ts",
        "./tsDefinitions/phaser.d.ts"
    ]    
}
```

Any ideas why it behaves like this?
It's a bit annoying because that spot launches my game code. Is it possible to start my 'Boot.runApp()' function from a  tag in my index.html?

Comment: What is `Boot` and what does it do? How are you actually running this code? Basically we need a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

When you `import`/`export` you create a module. You are using SystemJS (`module: system` in your tsconfig). Modules are wrapped in system register blocks:

```js
System.register("index", [], function (exports_2, context_2) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_2 && context_2.id;
    return {
        setters: [],
        execute: function () {
            window.onload = function () {
                console.log("Test");
            };
        }
    };
});
```

You need to run something like `System.import('index.js');` to run that code. When your typescript file is not a module, the `window.onload` is put directly into the compiled output, not wrapped in a `System.register`, which means it will be immediatly executed when you load the file.